# Is it possible to boost an elasticsearch match with regex?

Tags: python, regex, elasticsearch

So I've been working with elasticsearch, I'm encountering a problem where I'm struggling to boost my match using a regex, so for example if I query "document 524106", I want it to match the field, then if the matched number matches my regex `[0-9]{5,}` the score will get boosted.
So I tried combining my match query with regexp but that wouldn't work, no matter what I do, the regexp will boost any document containing a number that matches the regex, I tried doing a must containing both match and regexp, I tried using regexp as a filter, I tried separating the two, Is anyone able to help me figure out if it's even possible ?

I tried multiple queries including a must query, a filter, combining the two, so the last thing I tried was this and still didn't get the solution I'm thinking about

```
content_query.append(
    {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "document.number".format(lang): {
                            "query": token
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "regexp": {
                        "document.number".format(lang): {
                            "value": "[0-9]{5,}",
                            "boost": 5
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "regexp": {
                                "document.number".format(lang): {
                                    "value": "[0-9]{5,}"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "document.number".format(lang): {
                                    "query": token
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

To give more examples:
Let's say I have 3 documents

```
Document 1
Title : this is document 1
document: I have 56000 dollars in my bank account
```

```
Document 2
Title : this is document 2
document: I have 123695 dollars in my bank account
```

```
Document 3
Title : this is document 3
document: I have 52.85 dollars in my bank account
```

The way I'm indexing is I'm separating the text from the numbers hence the document.number to query. the regex i'm using to index numbers is `"\d+\s*\-?\.?\s*\d+"`
if I query "56000 dollars" with a match and a regexp, it should match 56000 with both the match query and regexp so it gets boosted, for some reason the regex is boosting every other number as well which is not what I want

Comment: you should give an example with documents that should be found, which not and which should be boosted

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, then the following query is a solution

```
GET /regexp_fields/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
                {
                    "regexp": {
                        "text": "[0-9]{5,}"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "text": "dollars"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "tie_breaker": 0.8
        }
    }
}
```

for documents

```
PUT /regexp_fields/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"title" : "this is document 1", "text": "I have 56000 dollars in my bank account"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"title" : "this is document 2", "text": "I have 123695 dollars in my bank account"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"title" : "this is document 3", "text": "I have 52.85 dollars in my bank account"}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "regexp_fields",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 1.1068251,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "this is document 1",
                    "text" : "I have 56000 dollars in my bank account"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "regexp_fields",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 1.1068251,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "this is document 2",
                    "text" : "I have 123695 dollars in my bank account"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "regexp_fields",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 0.13353139,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "this is document 3",
                    "text" : "I have 52.85 dollars in my bank account"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```